# Python.exe crash with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I started using PyQt5 for dynamic javascript scraping and already ran into trouble. When i have multiple urls to scrape, python crashes after first or second url, no matter what the domain. I can get data from the first,  but not from the second page. Error logs from windows show Qt5WebEngineCore.dll as the cause of error, but I got no clue what to do. I really didnt find anything useful on it from elswhere on the web.
Here's the code:

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


class Client(QWebEnginePage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))    #Ignote mainFrame from PyQt4
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def scrape_pyqt5():
    lists = ['example1.com/a', 'example1.com/b', 'example1.com/c']
    for url in lists:
        r = Client(url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(r.html, 'html.parser')
        for link in bs.find_all('div', {'id': 'media-player'}):
            for directlink in link.find_all('iframe'):
                print(directlink)
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: i added it to the main question

Comment: I think it's because of this line: `self.load(QUrl(url))`. The object gets garbage collected. Pull it out of the function and don't make it disappear so python thinks it is needed.

Comment: okay, but what excatly do you mean by 'don't make it dissapear'?

Comment: @murdock477 I mean, do something with that instance. Like `self.url = QUrl(url); self.load(self.url)`. I might be utterly wrong, though. Just an assumption, hence a comment. By "don't make it disappear" I mean: pretend you need the object so that it never expires and gets out of the scope and gets GC'ed.

Comment: thank you, but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Okay, I thought I understood what you said (I didn't), but then I realized I'm running the object again and again every time I loop to another URL! Ill try to figure something out now.